# what can i use to get every 9 numbers before a specific letter in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

This is a a part of my string

```
"J2 ^_F& [1] 1 2 7= 578094751V [#`\$5J ];)$#KD>&#Z S$5& 8=b#c 3 804290151V d)#KD+J ];)$#KD>&#Z GMe" f8&J [#`S&)+ [1] 1/1 4 7= g:)"
```

my requirement is to get the numbers like 578094751 out of this string

what kind of function i can use to extract these data

Comment: Hi Shan! Please share any code you've tried if you want an answer. You'll get downvoted a lot with a question this specific that doesn't show what you've attempted already :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex like so:

```
/\d{9}V/gm
```

Meaning get every match which has 9 digits followed by a V. In JavaScript you can get this as an array by doing:

```js
var foo ="J2 ^_F& [1] 1 2 7= 578094751V [#`\$5J ];)$#KD>&#Z S$5& 8=b#c 3 804290151V d)#KD+J ];)$#KD>&#Z GMe\" f8&J [#`S&)+ [1] 1/1 4 7= 567321471V g:)";
var regex = /\d{9}V/gm;
console.log(foo.match(regex))
```

*Note*: The provided string wasn't valid so I escaped the middle quote.

Comment: thanks that worked perfectly that was a big help

Answer (score 0):

Try `/((\d){9}\w)/ig` as it is more generic and it is implying that you want to select 9 consecutive digits followed by a character.

```js
const foo ="J2 ^_F& [1] 1 2 7= 578094751V [#`\$5J ];)$#KD>&#Z S$5& 8=b#c 3 804290151V d)#KD+J ];)$#KD>&#Z GMe\" f8&J [#`S&)+ [1] 1/1 4 7= 567321471V g:)";
var regex = /((\d){9}\w)/ig
console.log(foo.match(regex))
```

Comment: \w matches numbers too. ;-)